# AVR or Arduino Profibus interface project?

Tags: arduino, avr, profibus

Is there an open source solution to interface any profibus slave or master chips?

These are the latest finds for a Profibus slave AVR solution:

- AVR GCC with up to **[187.5Kbps profibus slave in software](http://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/106174)**
- AVR GCC with up to **[12Mbps profibus slave in hardware](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?module=Freaks%20Academy&func=viewItem&item_id=2587&item_type=project)**
- AVR ASM with up to **[187.5Kbps profibus slave in software](http://www.htw-dresden.de/fe/labor/mikror/projects/pb_slave/index.htm)**

Comment: Unfortunately ASM link no longer lives, so if you need it write it here and I will not be lazy if there is a real demand for it.

Comment: Please post all three as answers, and accept whichever is best for you.  Customs on this site have changed a bit since this post was made, and XTL's single-link answer isn't acceptable anymore (and the "you must log in" pages for the first two don't bode well either).  You have room for 30,000 characters, and using the "code" button will turn it into a code block.  Thanks so much for updating this!

Comment: @Kevin: I have posted a working ASM link as an answer, just as you asked for. I did it for SoftPB C version also, although I really couldn't see that forum asks for login (just downloaded file without any forum account). As for HardPB C version I don't think I have a good solution. AVRfreaks requests login to reach projects section. StackExchange doesn't accept attachments, and 415KB of sources is not something you can fit in 30.000 chars code block. If you PM me your mail I can send you 73KB zipped file, or suggest something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working link for AVR GCC source with up to **[187.5Kbps profibus slave in software](http://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/76882/AVRSoftBus.zip)**. This is the **[original forum link](http://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/106174)**, and online google translation breaks before reaching important part, so I didn't provide the link for it.

Answer (score 2):

No idea, but since I googled, I might just paste this:
http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=692535

Comment: bah; I clicked the arrow by mistake and I can't "clear" it. Leaving it at -1 since the link doesn't really provide much in the way of answers and the links the link provides lead only to commercial solutions or dead links. (I was really hoping to see the 187kbps AVR code!)

Comment: nevermind, bumped to +1 since I was eventually able to find this link from it. http://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/106174

Answer (score 1):

ProfiBus-DP is just RS-485; electrically this is not a challenge. If you're going after PA it's a little trickier, as you might have some trouble sourcing onesie-twosie quantities, but I can't imagine an Arduino talking on the PA network anyway, so let's not worry about it.

I think your biggest challenge will be in finding or developing an protocol stack. I wrote a CIP (DeviceNet and Ethernet/IP) protocol stack for a project several years ago and that was quite a challenge. Designing to industrial specifications isn't easy. I swear that they develop the specifications in order to give consultants work. :-)

You can buy networking stacks from various suppliers, but they aren't cheap, and you will likely have to do a lot of porting (and thus compliance testing) work to get it to work on something like Arduino.

Good luck! It will be a challenging project!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working link for AVR ASM with up to **[187.5Kbps profibus slave in software](http://web.archive.org/web/20070714172355/http://www.htw-dresden.de/fe/labor/mikror/projects/pb_slave/index.htm)**. This is an **[online translation](http://translate.google.com/translate?langpair=auto%7Cen&u=http://web.archive.org/web/20070714172355/http://www.htw-dresden.de/fe/labor/mikror/projects/pb_slave/index.htm)** if you don't know german, and this is **[the source](http://web.archive.org/web/20070714172420/http://www.htw-dresden.de/fe/labor/mikror/projects/pb_slave/software.zip)** and **[schematic](http://web.archive.org/web/20070714172420/http://www.htw-dresden.de/fe/labor/mikror/projects/pb_slave/hardware.zip)**. All with a little help of a **[Wayback Machine](http://www.archive.org/web/web.php)** ;-)